# Problem accessing Google API environment variable in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to authorize Google Sheets in some Python code deployed on Heroku. I have my Google service account authorization stored as an environment variable in Heroku.

```
credentials = environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=credentials)
```

However, when I run the script on Heroku, I get an error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Followed by the entire JSON dump of my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.

```
'{\n  "type": "service_account", [...] gserviceaccount.com"\n}'
```

This works fine locally on my machine when I have the JSON file in the project folder.

Here's the full traceback leading up to the FileNotFoundError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "code.py", line 27,
>   in 
>       gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=credentials)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygsheets/authorization.py",
>   line 111, in authorize
>       credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file,
>   scopes=scopes)   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py",
>   line 209, in from_service_account_file
>       filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py",
>   line 71, in from_filename
>       with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Need to convert the environment variable to JSON with json.loads, *then write that to a JSON file* with json.dump. This is because pydrive only accepts service credentials as a JSON file, and the Heroku env vars are not actually stored as JSON, even they're created from a JSON file.

```
#AUTHENTICATE
gauth = GoogleAuth()
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = json.loads(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
with open('gcreds.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(creds, fp)
gauth.credentials = 
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('gcreds.json', scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Answer (score 2):

@24hourbreakfast fwiw, I just added credentials-via-env-var support to the pygsheets lib:

https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/pull/345

Not sure when he'll do the next release, hopefully soon.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you